# How do I calculate the load strength of an aluminum tube arm by length and thickness?

Tags: aluminum

I have a computer device currently mounted at the end of an alumnium 16" rod as provided by the manufacturer, but I need a 24" arm which they do not sell, so I want to buy some aluminum tubing 7/8" diameter to replace it. I found some that is only 1/16" thick. How thick does the aluminum tubing need to be at that length to support my 10 lb device (it's actually 7 lbs and I rounded up for safety.) To recap, the 10 lb weight will be attached to the end of the 24" horizontal arm of aluminum tubing.  How thick does the tubing need to be so as not to bend or crack?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look up supplementary info to this answer. I'm not going to lay out every detail here.

You need second moment of inertia of the tube which quantifies the tube's stiffness based on the geometry of the cross section. Since your tube is a simple shape you don't need to calculate it geometrically from scratch. Just look up a table of equations for second moment of inertia of simple shapes and pull the equation from there.

The 2nd moment of inertia is the multiplied by the yield strength of the material to get the bending strength.

I tried to outline the process but it go too wordy so I'm not going to. Basically you have two approaches to come up with your specification:

1. You can calculate your cantilever bending strength based on your own
   specifications.
2. Use the original beam as a reference. Calculate the bending strength of the original beam based on material, dimensions, and thickness. Then scale that bending strength up by the increase in length (since cantilever bending forces scale that way).

After you have your specification, calculate the beam strengths for the tubes available to you until you find one that meets or exceeds your specification.

Note that in everything described so far, the weight of the beam itself was not accounted for. This was the part that got too wordy. It's because the amount of material in the beam influences both the strength required to support itself, but also the strength that the beam can actually support. That's where you have to calculate the bending strength required and the actual bending strength over and over again until you find one that can support itself.

When accounting for self-weight of the beam, it's more direct in concept to add in the weight of the beam if you're cooking up your specification from scratch. But it may be easier (though more wordy to explain) to use the the original beam as a reference. You basically multiply the calculated specification of the original beam by various factors to account for the change in forces due to weight of the beam or strength difference in material:

- -Proportional difference in length
- Proportional difference in cross sectional area
- Proportional difference in material density

Also note the original beam is already specified to support its own weight, so if you straight up use the three factors above it will be overdoing it a bit. You can adjust for that if you like but you can think about that since it not difficult to do or think about but super wordy to actually talk about.

**NOTE:** None of this considers buckling failure. I think 1/16" hollow aluminum is too easily dented so even if the calculation says it will work, I would not go with it because if it's accidentally dented, it will buckle and the whole thing will fail. I *might* be comfortable with 1/16" steel in this regard, but not aluminum.